# scala abstract class: Not able to access constructor paramater

Tags: scala

I am not able to access the class constructor parameter in the body of the function. In Scala the constructor parameter becomes the class member with appropriate get/set defined.
But in the below example, i am not able to refer to the constructor parameter 'p'. Is there something i am doing wrong? do i need to put a prefix?

```
abstract class MyFunc(in: Int) extends Function1[Int, Boolean] {
    val x : Int = 10
}

val dunc = new MyFunc(10) {
  def apply(p: Int): Boolean = {
    p % in == 0  << compilation error. 'in' value not found
    // p % x == 0  << compiles fine
  }
}
```

I am able to access an explicitly defined member variable but not the constructor defined variable. Why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default constructor parameters are **private**: so they are visible only in class itself. But you change this behaviour:

```
abstract class MyFunc(protected val in: Int) extends Function1[Int, Boolean] {
    val x : Int = 10
}
```